# Question mark at end of printf

Tags: c, string

Here is a simple code of reversing the string in C the last printf statement prints the reverse order , but with a question mark at the end, while I just want to print the reversed string not the question mark
How do I fix it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
char new_string[100];
char string[100];
scanf("%s",string);
printf("original_number = %s\n",string);
int i;
int l = strlen(string)-1;

for(i = 0; i<=l; i++){
 new_string[i] = string[l-i];
 printf("%c\n",new_string[i]);
    }
 printf("rev_number = %s\n",new_string);
}
```

input :  abcd

output:
  original_number = abcd

d

c

b

a

rev_number = dcba?

Comment: `char new_string[100];` --> `char new_string[100]={0};`

Comment: Woah! , it worked, could you tell me the logic behind ,  char new_string[100]={0};

Comment: Since `new_string` has not been initialized, garbage is displayed. It is necessary to initialize with 0 beforehand or add null-terminator(`'\0'`) after the character string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to null terminate your string. 
Add this line at after the for loop where you reverse string.

`new_string[i]='\0';`

```
for(i = 0; i<=l; i++){
   new_string[i] = string[l-i];
   printf("%c\n",new_string[i]);
}
new_string[i]='\0'; // add this 
printf("rev_number = %s\n",new_string);
```

[check-here](http://ideone.com/BuiSZr)

Answer (score 0):

If the question is "How to add '?' to the end of string?" I have to answers:

1) use `strcat` to add one more character, e.g.:

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char new_string[101] = {0}; // +1 to be sure that enough place for '?' will be available
                                // {0} to init empty string
    char string[100];
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("original_number = %s\n", string);
    int i;
    int l = strlen(string) - 1;
    for (i = 0; i <= l; i++){
        new_string[i] = string[l - i];
        printf("%c\n", new_string[i]);
    }
    strcat(new_string, "?");
    printf("rev_number = %s\n", new_string);
}
```

2) put `?` and add character `\0` after the loop end, e.g.:

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    char new_string[101]; // +1 to be sure in place for '?'
    char string[100];
    scanf("%s", string);
    printf("original_number = %s\n", string);
    int i;
    int l = strlen(string) - 1;
    for (i = 0; i <= l; i++){
        new_string[i] = string[l - i];
        printf("%c\n", new_string[i]);
    }
    // add one more char
    new_string[i] = '?';
    // set the string end
    new_string[i + 1] = '\0';
    printf("rev_number = %s\n", new_string);
}
```

Pay attention, that if you fill all the array with `0` as `char new_string[101] = {0};`, you do not need to add end of string with `new_string[i + 1] = '\0';`, so the second variant can be shorter if initialization is as in the first one

For both snippets I have the same output

[image]

**UPDATE:**

One more advice on working with strings. When input is made with `scanf` and you know how much characters can be stored in your array of chars use the following approach to prevent violation of the array boundaries

```
char string[10]; // if you have 10 bytes 
scanf("%9s", string); // ask not more than 9 characters
```

remember that you need one more byte for '\0' (null terminator).

Answer (score 0):

terminate new_string by new_string[i]='\0' after for-loop

Answer (score -1):

the problem is you are taking "end of string" as the last input in for loop.you do not need the variable "l". you can do some think like that

```
int main()
{
    char new_string[100];
    char string1[100];
    scanf("%s",string1);
    printf("original_number = %s\n",string1);
    int i;


    for(i = 0; i<=strlen(string1); i++){
     new_string[i] = string1[i-1];

     printf("%c\n",new_string[i]);
        }
     printf("rev_number = %s\n",new_string);
}
```